# Drag gesture not working when using a function returning a View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a View with an element that has drag gesture, which is working fine. However, I am trying to use a modifier function to put the whole thing in a ZStack and present something else on top of it as well optionally. If I use the `additionalView` modifier, the drag gesture stops working. I even tried to use it with an `EmptyView()`, and also tried to return just `body` within `additionalView`, the drag gesture was not working. For some reason the `translation` variable is not updating in `DragGesture.updating` however `value` has the correct value. Tried also to use `@State`
instead of `@GestureState` and update it manually, that didn't work either. Maybe not using a function for presenting an optional view but using an optional `@ViewBuilder` parameter in the view's constructor and put the ZStack in body would do the trick, but I like more this approach.

```
struct DragTest: View {
    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Spacer()
                Text("some text")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
            .offset(x: self.translation)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.width
                    print(value.translation.width)
                    print(self.translation)
                }
            )
        }
    }

    func additionalView<AdditionalView: View>(@ViewBuilder additionalView: @escaping () -> AdditionalView) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.body
            additionalView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DragTest()
            .additionalView {
                EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are invoking the `body` of the view within itself recursively, this should lead to troubles